# Javascript function to replace data in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid on the start page of a .NET Core 2.0 MVC web app. The data source is populated via ViewData on page load:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var allForms = formsDB.FormHeader.Select(x => x);
    ViewData["AllForms"] = allForms;
    <...>

    return View();
}
```

The data source object (FormHeader) contains a column with an employee code. One of the columns in my Kendo grid is currently displaying the employee code, but I'd like to display the full name via .ClientTemplate:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Forms.Models.FormHeader>()
          .Name("HeadersMasterGrid")
          .BindTo((IQueryable<Forms.Models.FormHeader>)ViewData["AllForms"])
          .Pageable()
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeCode).Title("Employee")
                    /*.ClientTemplate("#=getEmployeeName(EmployeeCode)#")*/;
          <..>
```

I'd like to display the employee's first and last name instead of the code. I set up an IAction result in my Form Controller to receive an employee code and return the full name (via ~/Form/GetEmployee/):

```
public ActionResult GetEmployee(string id)
    {
        var employee = theDB.EmployeeMasters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeCode.Trim() == id.ToUpper());
        BasicEmployee basicEmployee = new BasicEmployee(employee.FirstName, employee.LastName, id.Trim());
        //return Json(basicEmployee);
        return Json(basicEmployee.FullName);
    }
```

Lastly, I added some jQuery script to my view that I was hoping would open the URL, retrieve the full name, and return that into the .ClientTemplate of the Kendo Grid column. You can see that I have tried returning just the full name, but also returning the entire object and then parsing/returning the full name from the object.
The second function in the block below was my most recent attempt after receiving some instruction about promises/callbacks (which are still pretty fuzzy).

```
@*function getEmployeeName(empCode) {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetEmployee", "Form")' + "/" + empCode,
        function(data) {
            //var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            //return response.FullName.toString();
            return $.parseJSON(data);
        }, 'json');
}*@

function getEmployeeName(empCode) {
    var promise = $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetEmployee", "Form")' + "/" + empCode);
    $.when(promise).done(function(data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    });
}
```

I've spent quite a bit of time with the Kendo docs, Google, and two Slack workspaces for developers, but I'm not finding anything that works. I have no experience with either Javascript or jQuery before this project and am still very much in the learning phase. I understand that I am most likely going about this incorrectly (or missing an easy solution), but I'd like to know how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah, don't make more server calls. Populate your model with all the data you need before you call the grid. So you could add a FullName property that formats server side, or just return first and last names and use kendo's [hash syntax](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#hash-literals) to format client side:  `...ClientTemplate("<span>#= LastName #, #= FirstName #</span>");`

Comment: ... this sounds so logical now that I'm seeing it. I'm not sure why I didn't just do this in the first place. Sounds like the easiest action is to create a new object, populate that with the data from the FormHeader table, but include a property for the full name and display that. Thanks for the reminder!